# Scanner: scan int or string

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int, java.util.scanner

Trying to use the Scanner to take either an int or a string.. the code below is what I have:

```
System.out.println("where would you like to send the following item: ");
System.out.println("1. groceries, 2. savings, 3. utilities");
System.out.print("Enter list name or list number to send: ");
String user = user_input.nextLine();
      if (user.toLowerCase().equals("groceries") || Integer.parseInt(user) == 1) {
             System.out.println("item was sent to the grocery list");

      }else if(user.toLowerCase().equals("savings") || Integer.parseInt(user) == 2) {
             System.out.println("item was sent to the savings list");

      }else if(user.toLowerCase().contains("utilities") || Integer.parseInt(user) == 3) {
             System.out.println("item was sent to the utilities list");

      }else{
             System.out.println("item is not in any category");

      }
```

My issue is that I keep getting a NumberFormatException error whenever I type in a String. Typing an int doesn't give me any problems. I thought taking the input using `String user = user_input.nextLine();` and converting a number string to an int in the if statement using `Integer.parseInt(user)` would do the trick but it's still giving me the error message.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: `parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException` if the input string does not represent an integer. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: You can avoid `parseInt` with `user.equals("1")` etc.

Comment: Let me clarify: `if (user.toLowerCase().equals("groceries") || user.equals("1")) {`, etc.

Comment: my apologies @JohnnyMopp ... I should have known thats what you meant... that actually does work... thank you. You helped me fix my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing user.equals("1") instead of Integer.parseInt(user) == 1. Or assume that the exception java.lang.NumberFormatException is valid and catch that exception and treat it the right way, for example:

```
    System.out.println("where would you like to send the following item: ");
    System.out.println("1. groceries, 2. savings, 3. utilities");
    System.out.print("Enter list name or list number to send: ");
    String user = user_input.nextLine();
    try {
          if (user.toLowerCase().equals("groceries") || Integer.parseInt(user) == 1) {
                 System.out.println("item was sent to the grocery list");

          }else if(user.toLowerCase().equals("savings") || Integer.parseInt(user) == 2) {
                 System.out.println("item was sent to the savings list");

          }else if(user.toLowerCase().contains("utilities") || Integer.parseInt(user) == 3) {
                 System.out.println("item was sent to the utilities list");

          }else{
                 System.out.println("item is not in any category");

          }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("item is not in any category");
    }
```

**Update:**

```
    System.out.println("where would you like to send the following item: ");
    System.out.println("1. groceries, 2. savings, 3. utilities");
    System.out.print("Enter list name or list number to send: ");
    String user = user_input.nextLine();
    if (user.toLowerCase().equals("groceries") || user.equals("1")) {
        System.out.println("item was sent to the grocery list");

    }else if(user.toLowerCase().equals("savings") || user.equals("2")) {
        System.out.println("item was sent to the savings list");

    }else if(user.toLowerCase().contains("utilities") || user.equals("3")) {
        System.out.println("item was sent to the utilities list");

    }else{
        System.out.println("item is not in any category");

    }
```

Comment: This won't work. For example, what happens if input is "savings"?

Comment: You are right. So the right solution for you is to use equals instead of Integer.paseInt. Going to edit my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but the issue could be that when entering a string it still attempts to parse an int, causing it to fail. For example, entering "2" works because "2" is a valid string and 2 is a valid int which can be parsed from the string "2", whereas "groceries" is a valid string but does not contain a valid int which can be parsed.

Comment: You can use a try-catch block before the if statements.
`int x;`
`try (x = Integer.parseInt(user)) {`
`// If statements for integer here`
`}`
`catch(NumberFormatException e) {`
`If statements for string here`
`}`
(Sorry for formatting, can't quite get it right)

Answer (score 0):

Odd822 is right. The problem is that when you enter any string other than "groceries", the program attemps to Integer.parseint("stringwhichisnotaninteger").
Therefore, it throws an exception.

This code should work:

```
if (user.toLowerCase().equals("groceries") || user.equals("1") ) {
        System.out.println("item was sent to the grocery list");

    }else if(user.toLowerCase().equals("savings") || user.equals("2")) {
        System.out.println("item was sent to the savings list");

    }else if(user.toLowerCase().contains("utilities") || user.equals("3")) {
        System.out.println("item was sent to the utilities list");

    }else{
        System.out.println("item is not in any category");

    }
```

Comment: He said using user.equals causes another problem above so I just assumed some problem happens that way. Editing my answer now.

Comment: That can causes issues when you compare words that contain uppercase letters, like "Groceries", but isn't an issue for numbers. Thanks for the edit.